# 80s or 90s cartoon. Alien robots come to Earth to steal our gold to turn into energy. 'World Defense Corps' fight them

Tags: story-identification, robots, androids

Robots from outer space attack Earth, stealing gold to make energy. A high school boy discovers a way to make energy from gold by exposing it to special ray, he joins the 'World Defence Corps' to fight the robots and save the Earth's gold

I have a link to an [Arabic language version of the cartoon](https://www.stardima.com/watch/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%84%D9%85-%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%86-%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%AC_5cfffcf08.html) (screenshots below) and I've looked **all over the Internet** but with no luck at all. This film is 82 minutes long. I recently watched it and it was Arabic dubbed, I tried to reach the uploader and know the real name of it but he unfortunately didn't answer. The credits were cut from the video so I couldn't tie it to any studio or year or cast names.

I saw it once when I was just a little kid back in 1994. I know I know I'm too old now, but some old shows just remind us of how the 90s were the best years of 20th century. It's maybe a 80s cartoon.

[image: Two male characters looking at a machine with a big yellow window, octagon plague and two wheels on the front]

[image: Some robots collect gold bars from what looks to be a mine]

[image: Four gold bars on a plinth that has come out of the floor]

[image: A blonde male on a motorbike in a car park]

Comment: yep the literal translation for " فرقة القوة " is task force , Arabs will never translate any anime or cartoon the way it should be .

Comment: @Hardcore_Player The 90s were the best years of the 20th century only in the opinions  of those who were kids then.  People who were kids in the the 80s often think the 80s were the best years of the century, people  who were kids in the the 70s often think the 70s were the best years of the century, etc.  If you find a centenarian to talk to they might claim the 20s were the best years of the 20th century.  But I admit the 90s were the most scientifically advanced decade of the 20th century, so that is one objective standard that could be used to claim they were the best decade.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - That's why it's not uncommon to have TV shows set 20-30 years in the past. *Happy Days*, *Laverne & Shirley* and *That 70s Show* are some of the most popular ones.

Answer (score 11):

[This](https://www.stardima.com/watch/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%84%D9%85-%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%86-%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%82%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%AC_5cfffcf08.html) is the pilot episode for [*PowerMasters: World Defence Corps*](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8RJzA5UPlOMJ:https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-1988-11-20-8802180500-story.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk), a short-lived TV show that flopped so badly that the entire world forgot about it.

Assuming the pilot was well received (spoiler, it wasn't), the intention was to chop this into four individual episodes.

Basically it was a 90 minute toy catalogue.

[image: A PowerMasters toy box for "The M.A.R.S. Unit, Missile and Radar System"]

Comment: Good luck getting hold of a copy in English. For some reason the show had awful marketing but amazing lawyers who're still policing any uploads.

Comment: woooo thank you my friend soooo much , I really appreciate your efforts , I never thought that you would help me the way you did  , at least now I know the name of the film , May God bless you , thank you so much .

Comment: http://photobucket.com/gallery/user/StarRunn/media/cGF0aDovTGlvbmVsIC0gUG93ZXJNYXN0ZXJzICAwMSAgVG95IEZhaXIgIEZlYiAxOTg4ICBBRkEgIHRyaW0gIHRyYW5zX3pwczNhemoydnBuLmpwZw==/?ref=

Comment: May I ask how could you find the name of it , I really searched hard and had no clues what so ever , in a specific sceen on one of the machines , there was the name of the programmer: lucky , and the name of pilot: 2nd lieutenant , and the vichle was an assault vehicle powermaster , I searched for the name powermaster and the transformers- optimus prime picture appears .... so how did you find it ?

Comment: @Hardcore_Player - I did a search for "World Defense Corps", started excluding duplicates and obvious dead-ends using the -NOT feature on Google and found this on about page 12; https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/1987-lionel-power-masters-red-eye-515521670

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend , I appreciate your effort , may God bless you , I live in Bethlehem- Palestine , where Jesus Christ was born , I pray for God to bless you and pray that you'll have a great Christmas holiday this year . Thank you so much .

Comment: @Hardcore_Player - Great. Don't forget to click the "accept" button to show that this is the right answer.